# How do load a tab bar controller inside a view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I would like to know how to load a tab bar controller into a view, but i keep hitting this error. "'-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "browseView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'"

What I'm trying to do is, create a splash screen (UIView) with 5 buttons and when clicked, it'll load a UITabBarController with 6 tab bar items.

Please help.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. This question has been answered thus many times. A tabbarcontroller should be the root controller.

You could create the app so that when it loads it creates a uiview, adds it to the window and when the user clicks a button it removes this view from the window and creates programmatically a tabbarcontroller and it's child controllers and adds that to the window.

Comment: geeez.. i found a few sample of how to create tabbar programmatically, but im now where to implement it. do i run it on 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' function or on the '(ibaction) buttonAction:(id)sender' function?

Comment: I think I'd be inclined to do it in my appDelegate - call a method in the appDelegate from the buttonAction.

Answer (score 0):

You may try presenting the tabbarcontroller as a modal view though.